# How are the two definitions of Eulerian posets equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I have been following Stanley's [Enumerative combinatorics](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/putnam/enu_comb_stanley.pdf) for the definition of an Eulerian poset. It is defined as follows:

**Definition:** A finite graded poset $P$ with $\hat{0}$ and $\hat{1}$ is Eulerian if   $\mu_P(s,t)=(-1)^{l(s,t)}$ for all $s\leq t$ in $P$.

Also after checking [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_poset), I found another definition that says an Eulerian poset is a graded poset in which every non-trivial interval has the same number of elements of even ranks as of odd ranks.

Can someone guide me a little to see how these two definitions are equivalent? I might be missing something pretty basic here.

Comment: Is your DOUBT about https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWxrK.png resolved ?

Comment: Yes @Prem I got it. Every interval didn't have same number of elements of even ranks and odd ranks. So it doesn't satisfy either of the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed true that $\mu(s,t)=(-1)^{\ell(s,t)}\iff $ every nontrivial interval has an equal number of elements with even and odd ranks.

$(\!\!\implies\!\!)$ Fix $s<t$. Since $\mu$ is the inverse of the zeta function, $\zeta(s,t)=1$ for all $s\le t$, we know that
$$
\begin{align}
0
=\sum_{s\le r\le t}\mu(s,r)\color{gray}{\cdot 1}
=\sum_{s\le r\le t}(-1)^{\ell(s,r)}
=(-1)^{\ell(\hat 0,s)}\sum_{s\le r\le t}(-1)^{\ell(0,r)}.
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\ell(0,r)$ is the rank of $r$. Since the sum of $(-1)^{\text{rank}(r)}$ over the interval $[s,t]$ is zero, it follows that $[s,t]$ has an equal number of elements of even and odd rank.

($\Longleftarrow$) To prove, $\mu(s,t)=(-1)^{\ell(s,t)}$, define $\sigma(s,t):=(-1)^{\ell(s,t)}$. It suffices to show that $\sigma$ is an inverse to the zeta function. For any $s<t$, we compute
$$
(\sigma*\zeta)(s,t)
=\sum_{s\le r\le t}\sigma(s,r)\cdot \zeta(r,t)
=\sum_{s\le r\le t}(-1)^{\ell(s,r)}\cdot 1
=(-1)^{\ell(\hat 0,s)}\sum_{s\le r\le t}(-1)^{\text{rank}(r)}
$$
The assumption that $[s,t]$ has an equal number of even and odd rank elements then implies that $\sum_{s\le r\le t}(-1)^{\text{rank}(r)}=0$, meaning that $(\sigma * \zeta)(s,t)=0$ when $s<t$, while $(\sigma * \zeta)(s,s)=1$. This means $\sigma * \zeta$ is the identity, proving that $\sigma(s,t)=(-1)^{\ell(s,t)}=\mu$.